# OAuth2 client credentials

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0

So right now I'm implementing oauth2 in my server, but I just want to support the `client_credentials` grant. The thing is, the [node-oauth2-server](https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server) says that supports this type of grant, and I pretty much debugged the whole library, and there are some things that doesn't make sense to me.

As far as I understand, the `client_credentials` grant should work like this:

1. An internal request should be made to generate the `client_id` and `client_secret` for the client, this is the only time we will get the `client_secret` and we should give this to our client
2. The `client_id` should be stored in database with any extra data (like the account id associated or something like this) and a hash of `client_secret` so we can later validate it
3. The client sends a request to the server including the `client_id` and `client_secret`
4. The server should then generate an access token (in my case I will be using JWT) and return from the request. We also need to store this token in database so we can revoke the permission if needed
5. The client must use this access token in future requests to access resources from server, and the server will validate on each request if the token is valid (didn't expire, didn't lose permissions, etc)

I may be wrong about this, but this is what I need and this exactly what [C# Identity](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) does and it is explained [here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/).

In my case I'm working with nodejs. Actually is a NestJS project, so I was trying to use [this lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@boyuai/nestjs-oauth2-server) which is basically a wrapper for `node-oauth2-server`, and if you take a look inside `node-oauth2-server`, looks like they only support authorization codes, this is because the `AuthorizeHandler.handle()` always returns an authorization code and `AuthenticateHandler.handle()` always expects the authorization code and returns the access token. Basically I need to call the `AuthenticateHandler.handle()` but instead of checking the authorization code, I must pass and check the `client_id` and `client_secret`.

This is a recent issue which has the exact same issue than me: https://github.com/oauthjs/node-oauth2-server/issues/552

So, first, I want to confirm that I'm right and this lib have this implemented in a bad way, and second, is there any other nodejs lib that has `client_credentials` built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned that it doesn't support `client_credentials` grant at the moment, you can still utilize the authorization code flow grant type internally to get the access token.

- Prepare client_credentials grant type request and submit to server.
- Map this request to authorization code flow with additional
  attributes require for the `authorization code` flow.
- Submit the request to Authorization server.
- Get the code from response.
- Prepare the token exchange call with the `oauth code`.
- Get the `access_token`.
- Return the token in response to client_credentials call.

Comment: This works. It's sad that I have to do something like this to work, I think the authors of the lib should implement the `client_credentials` behavior in the default flow of authorization